# Android: New buttons types

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement this type of buttons into my game but I don't know what it can be and how to use it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a progress bar? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html
You should give more context to the image.

Comment: Thanks Will, it's kinda of progress bar but I think it's customized one. How about the first one?

Comment: Button, prog. bar, prog. bar, button. Or those could be seek bars not progress bars. You can find posts here on Stackoverflow about how to customize your own bars or buttons.